# How can I get the access token to get google analytics Data?

Tags: java, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics to get the data for my website. I have tested the queries on query explorer. But I am unable to implement it in the code with OAuth. I need a access token to run my query, but my problem is I am unable to get the access token. Can anyone guide me through this.
Can anyone explain the relation between google developer console's to analytics account. 
Please refer to some implementation documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your own data that you want to access and you have access to the Google Analytics account website. I recommend you use a service account.  [Hello Analytics API Java](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java)

The Google Developer console is where you register your application with Google it has no relation to your Google Analytics account what so ever.

Again I recommend you go with a service account and create service account credentials on the Google Developer console. Take the service account email address add it as a user on your google analytics admin section at the account level give it read access it must be at the account level.   This will allow the service account to read your google analytics data.

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;

import com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.AnalyticsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Accounts;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.GaData;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Profiles;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Webproperties;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


/**
 * A simple example of how to access the Google Analytics API using a service
 * account.
 */
public class HelloAnalytics {


  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Hello Analytics";
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
  private static final String KEY_FILE_LOCATION = "/path/to/your.p12";
  private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL>@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Analytics analytics = initializeAnalytics();

      String profile = getFirstProfileId(analytics);
      System.out.println("First Profile Id: "+ profile);
      printResults(getResults(analytics, profile));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static Analytics initializeAnalytics() throws Exception {
    // Initializes an authorized analytics service object.

    // Construct a GoogleCredential object with the service account email
    // and p12 file downloaded from the developer console.
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
        .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsScopes.all())
        .build();

    // Construct the Analytics service object.
    return new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
  }


  private static String getFirstProfileId(Analytics analytics) throws IOException {
    // Get the first view (profile) ID for the authorized user.
    String profileId = null;

    // Query for the list of all accounts associated with the service account.
    Accounts accounts = analytics.management().accounts().list().execute();

    if (accounts.getItems().isEmpty()) {
      System.err.println("No accounts found");
    } else {
      String firstAccountId = accounts.getItems().get(0).getId();

      // Query for the list of properties associated with the first account.
      Webproperties properties = analytics.management().webproperties()
          .list(firstAccountId).execute();

      if (properties.getItems().isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("No Webproperties found");
      } else {
        String firstWebpropertyId = properties.getItems().get(0).getId();

        // Query for the list views (profiles) associated with the property.
        Profiles profiles = analytics.management().profiles()
            .list(firstAccountId, firstWebpropertyId).execute();

        if (profiles.getItems().isEmpty()) {
          System.err.println("No views (profiles) found");
        } else {
          // Return the first (view) profile associated with the property.
          profileId = profiles.getItems().get(0).getId();
        }
      }
    }
    return profileId;
  }

  private static GaData getResults(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
    // Query the Core Reporting API for the number of sessions
    // in the past seven days.
    return analytics.data().ga()
        .get("ga:" + profileId, "7daysAgo", "today", "ga:sessions")
        .execute();
  }

  private static void printResults(GaData results) {
    // Parse the response from the Core Reporting API for
    // the profile name and number of sessions.
    if (results != null && !results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("View (Profile) Name: "
        + results.getProfileInfo().getProfileName());
      System.out.println("Total Sessions: " + results.getRows().get(0).get(0));
    } else {
      System.out.println("No results found");
    }
  }
}
```

Code ripped directly from [Hello Analytics API: Java quickstart for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java)

Comment: thanks for the help, i am trying this.  I have added all the jars but it is giving me error:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpMethod